# Do I need to call finish() when using a GZIPOutputStream object inside try-wtth-resources block

Tags: java, gzipoutputstream, autocloseable

When using a GZipOutputStream inside of a try-with-resources [autoclosable] block, do I need to explicitly call `finish()` after I'm done with my resource?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `close()` method, which is called when leaving the try-with-resources block, calls `finish()`, so you do not need to do this manually.

You can see this in its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.java#DeflaterOutputStream.close%28%29) (`GZipOutputStream` does not override `close()`, so the `close()` method from its super class `DeflaterOutptuStream` is used). Also the [JavaDoc of `close()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#close()) states that it "Writes remaining compressed data to the output stream", which is the same as [`finish()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#finish()) is documented to do.