# Compressing byte[] to byte[] with GZIPOutputStream? Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream, gzipinputstream, bytearrayinputstream, gzipoutputstream

I am trying to compress and array of bytes into another array of bytes using `GZIPOutputStream` (in Java).

This is my code:

```
@Test
public void testCompressBytes() throws IOException {
    final byte[] uncompressed = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(100000 /* 100 kb */).getBytes();

    // compress
    byte[] compressed;
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(uncompressed);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            OutputStream os = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);  // org.apache.commons.io
        os.flush();
        compressed = baos.toByteArray();
    }       
    System.out.println("Size before compression = " + uncompressed.length + ", after = " + compressed.length);

    // decompress back
    byte[] decompressedBack;
    try (InputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        IOUtils.copy(is, baos);  // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
        baos.flush();
        decompressedBack = baos.toByteArray();
    }
        
    assertArrayEquals(uncompressed, decompressedBack);
}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

```
Size before compression = 100000, after = 63920
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `((GZIPOutputStream)os).finish();` is what you need

Comment: @g00se - Hmmm, here they say that close() automatically called by the try-with-resources clause should be enough? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172953/do-i-need-to-call-finish-when-using-a-gzipoutputstream-object-inside-try-wtth

Comment: Well it wasn't enough for me;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everybody!
Although calling `GZIPOutputStream::finish()` before `ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray()` seems to do the trick, I believe it's better to completely close the GZIP stream first, which in turn forces us to keep `ByteArrayOutputStream` outside the `try-with-resources` clause.

So, my reworked compression part looks like that now:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(uncompressed);
        GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
    IOUtils.copy(is, gzos);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

IOUtils.closeQuietly(baos);
final byte[] compressed = baos.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `GZIPOutputStream::close` **before** calling `ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray`, so that `GZIPOutputStream` writes all the end bits.

In your current code you are calling `ByteArrayOutputStream::toByteArray` before `GZIPOutputStream::close` (via `try-with-resources`) that's why it doesn't work.